# Populate one dropdown list based on another dropdown list and get "value" instead of dropdown showing value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, html

I am trying to make two drop down which populate by another dropdown

Here is code

html

```
<form type=get action="action.php">
<select name="meal" id="meal" onChange="changecat(this.value);">
<option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
</select>
<select name="category" id="category">
<option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>

    var mealsByCategory = {
    A : {one:"Soup", two:"Juice"},
    B : {three:"Water", four:"Others"},
    C : {five:"Coffee", six:"Tea"}  
    };

    function changecat(value) {
        if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
        else {
            var catOptions = "";
            for (categoryId in mealsByCategory[value]) {
                catOptions += "<option value='" + mealsByCategory[value][categoryId] +"'>" + mealsByCategory[value][categoryId] + "</option>";
            }
            document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = catOptions;
        }
    }

</script>
```

I know my java script is not wrong.

I am looking for output like in dropdown value must be the object name and in the dropdrown the object value.

ie
when I click submit
site go
`action.php?meal=B&category=Juice`

Here you can see juice is passed (which apears on drop down) instead of it I need to pass  "two" which is object name of juice

like `action.php?meal=B&category=two`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assign `categoryId` as value of options

```js
var mealsByCategory = {
  A: {
    one: "Soup",
    two: "Juice"
  },
  B: {
    three: "Water",
    four: "Others"
  },
  C: {
    five: "Coffee",
    six: "Tea"
  }
};

function changecat(value) {
  if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
  else {
    var catOptions = "";
    for (categoryId in mealsByCategory[value]) {
      catOptions += "<option value='" + categoryId + "'>" + mealsByCategory[value][categoryId] + "</option>";
    }
    document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = catOptions;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form type=get action="action.php">
  <select name="meal" id="meal" onChange="changecat(this.value);">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
  </select>
  <select name="category" id="category">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```